# SQL recursive relationship triple layers

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, recursive-query, recursive-datastructures

So I have one table where I need to utilize a recursive relationship and select the employees of those who are supervised by those who are supervised by someone named Johnson.  I can only get those who are supervised directly by Johnson and this is my query so far:

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.fName, ' ', a.lName) AS employee_name, a.empNum, a.supervises    
FROM employees a   
WHERE supervises =   
(SELECT empNum    
FROM employees    
WHERE lName = 'Johnson'   
);
```

What do I need to do to adjust my select statement to get the next level of employees who are supervised by those supervised by Johnson?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all members in a tree structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631222/find-all-members-in-a-tree-structure)

Comment: @ZoharPeled nope that example has one column utilizing IDs this example has two columns?

Comment: doesn't matter. still a recursive cte is the easiest way to solve this.

Comment: _"that example has one column utilizing IDs this example has two columns"_ - that example has ID and ParentID. Same as your schema. Same as any other trivial tree/recursion schema.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I'll keep working at it.  I just wish someone could do it both ways not just CTE.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I have my CTE working but I just don't understand how to get it to produce the results how I require.  If I post what I have thus far would you be able to assist?

Comment: Anyone here would be happy to assist someone who'd demonstrate what one has tried. Besides, all the recursion CTE-based queries are totally similar one to another. Just rename columns and table names.

Comment: @IvanStarostin I think I am understanding this a bit better now thanks for not being too specific cuz even though it's late I needed that! So if I want to just get "those who are supervised by those who are supervised by the CEO (CEO being NULL for managerID)" just make it so that the CTE empLevel column is <=3? or = 3?  And this is per the Employee Heirarchy example at: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/1343/common-table-expressions/17992/recursive-cte#t=201611161238449479911)  At any rate thanks I think I just about have this...

Comment: `<=` or `=` - depends on your requirements, on what you want to get. Test it on sample data. It will return whole hyerarchy limited to 1-3 levels or just level 3.

Comment: @ZoharPeled sorry for my not understanding and my attitude at first I think I totally get this now and appreciate not just being handed the answer because it made me a better critical thinker about CTE.

Comment: @IvanStarostin thanks I appreciate it.  No more help needed.