# SQL - Get Entries linked to a given value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a Database similar to this:

[image: Example Table]

I look for a query to get all values from the Table where you can get to by following the linked values. I am not really sure how to express this with my english thats why it is a bit difficult for me to find proper solutions for this via Google.

Example:
I have the value: *Cd*
The result should now be something like this: *Ab, Bc, Cd, De, Ef* (The result doesn't have to be sorted)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all members in a tree structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40631222/find-all-members-in-a-tree-structure)

Comment: Just to get this clear: There are "paths" Where C2 conects to the next C1 or - vice versa - C1 connects to the previous C2. You pass in one node within the path and you want to get all members of this path (order not important. Might there be multiple paths (More than one previous/next node)?

Comment: @Shnugo Yes, i think there might be also multiple paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you can follow the links both ways, so you can do it like this using recursive common table expressions:

```
CREATE TABLE #t (C1 varchar(2), C2 varchar(2));

INSERT INTO #t values('Ab','Bc');
INSERT INTO #t values('Bc','Cd');
INSERT INTO #t values('Cd','De');
INSERT INTO #t values('De','Ef');
INSERT INTO #t values('Gh','Hi');
INSERT INTO #t values('Hi','Ij');

DECLARE @start varchar(2) = 'Cd';

WITH cte(vC1, vC2) AS 
(
    SELECT C1, C2 FROM #t WHERE C1 = @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C1, C2 FROM #t INNER JOIN cte ON vC2 = C1
),
cte2(vC1, vC2) AS
(
    SELECT C1, C2 FROM #t WHERE C2 = @start
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C1, C2 FROM #t INNER JOIN cte2 ON vC1 = C2
)
SELECT vC1 FROM cte
UNION -- unions here add an implicit DISTINCT
SELECT vC2 FROM cte
UNION 
SELECT vC1 FROM cte2
UNION 
SELECT vC2 FROM cte2
```

Comment: I like that approach, +1 form my side

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. As far as i can see at the moment this works perfectly!